# Can't call jquery function which was inserted code behind

Tags: c#, jquery

In my page, I have a user control which will insert a jQuery function when the switch turned on. And this is my code behind the user control:

```
public bool isRequired {
  set {
    if (value == true) {
      ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

      string csname = "isRequiredScript";
      if (!cs.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(this.GetType(), csname)) {
        StringBuilder cstext = new StringBuilder();
        cstext.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
        cstext.Append("$(document).ready(function () {");
        cstext.Append("function QuestionwithConditionalInfo_validation() {");
        cstext.Append("if ($(\"#MainPlaceHolder_" + QuestionOption.ClientID + " :checked\").val() == null) {");
        cstext.Append("alert(\"Please answer the question '" + setQuestionText + "'\");");
        cstext.Append("return false;");
        cstext.Append("}} });");
        cstext.Append("</script>");
        cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), csname, cstext.ToString(), false);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then in the main page, I planned to call that jQuery function:

```
function childpage_validation() {
  if (QuestionwithConditionalInfo_validation() == false)
    return false;
}

<asp:Button ID="page1_Next" Text="Next page" runat="server" OnClick="page1_Next_Command" OnClientClick="return childpage_validation()" />
```

Then I got the error said the function `QuestionwithConditionalInfo_validation()` is not defined, after that I tried `RegisterStartupScript` instead of `RegisterClientScriptBlock` which got the same error. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Take it out of the document ready, otherwise it isn't global and therefore can't be accessed from other scripts.

Comment: Also, why wouldn't you just `return QuestionwithConditionalInfo_validation()` instead of checking if it's true or false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understand that the document ready is only needed to allow it to execute during that event - it is an event handler really.  As you are not needing that (the event already occured), you can remove that from your code:

```
cstext.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
cstext.Append("function QuestionwithConditionalInfo_validation() {");
cstext.Append("if ($(\"#MainPlaceHolder_" + QuestionOption.ClientID + " :checked\").val() == null) {");
cstext.Append("alert(\"Please answer the question '" + setQuestionText + "'\");");
cstext.Append("return false;");
cstext.Append("}};");
cstext.Append("</script>");
```

Also by removing that, you remove its closure to it is now a global object and can be accessed from the page as you express your desire to do.